# How to count the amount of words with more than 3 letters?

Tags: c, char

I am trying to write a program that counts the amount of words that have more than three letters. The program has to end when a period is entered. My code works, but it fails to count the first word, so, if I enter three words with more than three letters, the output is two.

I tried to do the following: I count letters until the user clicks the spacebar. When that happens, I check whether the counter is larger than three. If it is, it increases the counterLargerThanThree by one. This runs continuously, until the user enters a period.  When the user enters a period, the program finishes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    int cont = 0, aux , counterLargerThanThree = 0;
    printf("Enter a phrase that ends with a period:\n");

    c = getchar();

    while(c != '.')
    {
        aux = c;
        c = getchar();
        cont++;

        if(aux == ' ')
        {
            if(cont>3)
            {
                counterLargerThanThree++;
            }

            cont = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%i \n",counterLargerThanThree);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not counting last word as when `.` period character comes you break the loop even if word length>3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your input (i.e. when a dot is encountered), the `while` loop is skipped, and you never get the chance to count that last word, if it happens to be more than three chars long.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int cont = 0, counterLargerThanThree = 0;
    printf("Enter a phrase that ends with a period:\n");

    do
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c != ' ' && c != '.')
        {
            ++cont;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cont > 3)
            {
                counterLargerThanThree++;
            }
            cont = 0;
        }
    }
    while (c != '.');

    printf("%i \n", counterLargerThanThree);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not counting the last word as when period character `.` comes you break the loop even if word length>3. Try something like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    int cont = 0, aux , counterLargerThanThree = 0;
    printf("Enter a phrase that ends with a period:\n");


    while(1)
    {
        c = getchar();
        cont++;

        if(c == ' ' || c=='.')
        {
            if(cont>3)
            {
                counterLargerThanThree++;
            }

            cont = 0;
        }
        if(c=='.'){
            break;
        }
    }


    printf("%i \n",counterLargerThanThree);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```